# Clear cell content in a range if value is negative

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm triyng to make my macro able to clear cells if their value is negative.
In particular, the macro should clear all negative cells in columns H to K until last row in column A.

I tried this code I've found on the net but I really don't know how to extend it to columns I to K (works only for column H).

```
Dim LC1 As Long, ColNum1 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For ColNum1 = 8 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  For LC1 = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum1).End(xlUp).Row
     If Val(CStr(Cells(LC1, ColNum1))) < 0 Then Cells(LC1, ColNum1) = 0
  Next LC1
Next ColNum1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I tried to replicate this code changing each time the value ColNum# to 9, 10 and 11 but it's not working. Why?

Comment: I would first suggest that you create a variable for the Column and row you want to go to, so that can be a separate line and make the For loops a little more clear.  When you say it's not working, is there an error generated? Does nothing happen to the values? Does it replace everything with "1000000"? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
' Get last row of col A...
Dim lastRow as long, r As Long, c As Long
Range("A1").select
lastRow = Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow
For c = 8 To 11

    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, c)) Then
        If Cells(r, c) < 0 Then
            Cells(r, c).ClearContents
        End If
    End If     

Next
Next
```